# Button is not working in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following code here:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="centering col-lg-8 topSection" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 160px;">
                <h2 style="color: #fff; font-size: 30px;">Get discovered - Discover - Connect</h2>

                <h3 style="color: #fff; font-size: 23px;">We love everyting about music. The scene. The people. The livestyle. We live for it.</h3>
                <button type="submit" class="btn_style_1 btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalLogin">Sign in</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn_style_1 btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Join now</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the application, the buttons are not working. Nothing happens when I click on the buttons. The cursor Is not transformed to a pointer when I hover the buttons.

However, when I remove `centering col-lg-8 topSection`, the Sign in button works, but not the other button.

Have anyone had the same problem?

EDIT:

I had this In my Layout.cshtml:

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

When I removed the div, It worked.

Comment: or use <input type="submit">

Comment: @chirag Shouldn't use submit.

Comment: Is `float` involved here somewhere? .. It sounds like your buttons is beneath (layer) another element and as such not clickable but visible

Comment: but if he want to use submit for any reason, otherwise <button type="button"> as you said

Comment: @chirag To submit a form, yes, but he use it for toggling

Comment: Post your custom CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `type="submit"` or replace it with `type="button"`. Your solution would be:

```
<button type="button" class="btn_style_1 btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalLogin">Sign in</button>
<button type="button" class="btn_style_1 btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Join now</button>
```